# MoviePy problem with videos with different FPS and TBR

Tags: python, moviepy

I have a problem with videos with different FPS and TBR.

I open a video and try to render it:

```
video = movieEditor.VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
video.write_videofile('video.mp4')
```

**In the video where FPS == TBR (30)**
At the output, I get a video with normal playback speed.

**In video where FPS: 30, TBR: 120**
At the output, I get a video with normal playback speed.

**In video where FPS: 30, TBR: 240**
The output is a video with a very **high** playback speed and normal sound.

Then I open the video like this:

```
video = movieEditor.VideoFileClip('video.mp4', fps_source='fps')
video.write_videofile('video.mp4')
```

**In the video where FPS == TBR (30)**
At the output, I get a video with normal playback speed.

**In video where FPS: 30, TBR: 120**
At the output, I get a video with a very **low** playback speed and normal sound.

**In video where FPS: 30, TBR: 240**
At the output, I get a video with normal playback speed.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?
I tried to write video just with ffmpeg and there was no such problem.

Here's a video where you can do the tests:
[tbs_test.zip](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/files/6359502/tbs_test.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, but have you tried specifying the fps when writing the video file?

```
video.write_videofile('video.mp4', fps=30, threads = 4)
```